# Calling selectors from multiple file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, selector, nsnotifications

In AppDelegate.m, I've defined

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "allerta.h"

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize window = _window;

-(void)awakeFromNib {

// Add an observer that will respond to loginComplete
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(alerticonstatus:) 
                                             name:@"alert" object:nil];

// Post a notification to loginComplete
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"alert" object:nil];
}
@end
```

I want to call **alerticonstatus** from allerta.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface allerta : NSObject{
}

-(void)alerticonstatus:(NSNotification *)note;

@end
```

allerta.m:

```
#import "allerta.h"
@implementation allerta

-(void)alerticonstatus:(NSNotification *)note {

NSLog(@"called alerticonstatus");

}
@end
```

Can I import a function whit @selector from another file like allerta.h?
Now I have SIGABRT error.
Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you method for this, it work:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "allerta.h"

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize window = _window;

-(void)awakeFromNib {
   allerta *_allerta = [allerta alloc]; //allocation memory

   // Add an observer that will respond to loginComplete
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:_allerta //here you called self, but you need to call your class allerta
                                         selector:@selector(alerticonstatus:) 
                                             name:@"alert" object:nil];
    [_allerta release]; //kill _allerta class if you don't need more

    // Post a notification to loginComplete
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"alert" object:nil];
}
@end
```

When you create class files, set firs letter big, like as "Allerta".

Comment: Thanks Infog. I need [_allerta release]; in OSX?

Comment: Then you make allocation memory (alloc, copy, new) for object, you need make release for object than you don't need that object. You need to read more information about development for Objective-C.

Comment: You can change `allerta *_allerta = [allerta alloc];` to `*_allerta = [[allerta alloc] autorelease];` and then you don't need write `[_allerta release];`

Comment: I know the use of release, but xcode send me a error: "release is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode". alert release, not _allerta release because alloc allerta not _allerta

Comment: your project was created in XCode 4.2, and compatible with iOS 5.0 and and higher. In this way you mustn't use release.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you declare AppDelegate as receiver of `alerticonstatus` message when AppDelegate doesn't have this method declared. You are doing this in this line:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(alerticonstatus:) 
                                             name:@"alert" object:nil];
```

Your solution would be to change observer from `self` which in this case is AppDelegate to some allerta object. Just alloc-init some `allerta` object and add it as observer.